# In two dimension space, why two eigenvector cannot be at right angels to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When I read the wikipedia about [eigenvector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors), it said:

> If two-dimensional space is visualized as a rubber sheet, a linear map with two eigenvectors would be a stretching along two directions corresponding to the eigenvectors. For example, the sheet could be stretched by a factor $\lambda_1$ along the x-axis and $\lambda_2$ along the y-axis. In two dimensions, there can be two such independent stretching directions, but they need not be at right angles to each other.

I am confused by the the last sentence. Why they cannot be at right angles(perpendicular) to each other? Actually, in that the page, an example with two dimension space, the eigenvector are perpendicular to each other(One is (1,1), another one is (1,-1)).

Comment: "Need not" means "don't need to be".  It doesn't mean, "cannot be".

Comment: It didn't say they can't be orthogonal just that it is not a requirement, there can be eigenvectors that are not orthogonal

Comment: Thanks....I am poor at english grammar。

Comment: I'm a native speaker and also think "need not" was a poor choice for a technical explanation in this case.